# Jquery - How to get page number from link href and use as class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, click, href

I am working on a custom filtering system and for one of my functions, I need to get the page number from href of the clicked link. My URL looks like this--

**mysite.com/page/2/?address&s=Search.....**

I've tried the following code but it doesnt seem to be working.

```
$('.goforward').click(function() {
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  var selector = $(this).attr('page'); // make selector equal to the value we put in 'page'
  var pageNum = $(this).attr("href").match(/page="([0-9]+)"/)[1]; // get page number
  var fdd1 = $('[name="rating_score"]').val();
  var fdd2 = $('[name="value_score"]').val();

  // Create div with class iso-pageNum
  $('.isotope').append($('<div class="iso-' + pageNum '">').load(href + ".html .isotope > *", function() {
    select1f();
    select2f();

    if ($("select[name=rating_score] option:selected").val() == 'allr') {} else {
      // Select recent created div
      $('.isotope .iso-' + pageNum).children('div:not(' + fdd1 + ')').hide();
    }
  }));
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the page number like following.

```
var url = 'mysite.com/page/2/?address&s=Search';
var arr = url.split('/');
var pageNum = arr[arr.indexOf('page') + 1];

console.log(pageNum)
```

Answer (score 1):

make it

```
var href = $(this).attr('href'); //assuming href is mysite.com/page/2/?address&s=Search.....

var pageNumber = href.split( "/?" )[ 0 ].split( "/" ).pop();

alert(pageNumber); //this will alert 2
```

Comment: this gets me the site url "mysite.com"

Comment: @mygm26 I tried it in my browser console, it gave me `2`. what is the value of your `href`?

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
var href = "mysite.com/page/2/?address&s=Search..";

console.log(href.split("/page/")[1].split("/")[0]);
```